# getResponseCode() method doesn't return expected response code

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have 2 questions about Google App Script Services getResponseCode() method.

#### 1) "Unexpected Error"

When I run the getResponseCode() method, I got "Unexpected Error...".

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode()

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

Unexpected error: https://www.example.com/
```

※I can't tell the url for business reasons.

HTTP response status codes don't include "Unexpected Error".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Please tell me what response codes actually return, when this error occurs?

#### 2) getResponseCode() method didn't work as expected

When I run the code below, I got "200".

I expected "301" in response to the "**http**://google.com/" request.

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://google.com/");
　Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
}
```

I think getResponseCode() method doesn't return actual http status codes.

Please tell me why I got "200" instead of "301".

[get 301 response in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLvvw.png)

[get 200 response instead of 301](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ6G2.png)

Comment: For your first question, you'll need to post the code that gives you "Unexpected Error..."

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I posted the code, but I can't tell the url for business reason.

Comment: Does `response.getResponseCode()` return "Unexpected Error" or does it _throw_ an error (in a red box)? What is the output of `Logger.log(response)`?

Comment: response.getResponseCode() return "Unexpected Error" .This time the result is  ```[19-11-13 19:39:06:709 PST] 301.0```, but I got "Unexpected Error" yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the request is following the redirect. Take a look at the available parameters in the [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) method. You'll see `followRedirects`, which defaults to `true`.

Make this small change and you'll get the expected `301`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://google.com/", { followRedirects: false });
　Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I'll try it.